# Adding ActivityIndicator to Webview Tab app

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm trying to add a "loading" indicator in the center of my screen after each tab is selected and as the initial tab is loaded. I have found many posts showing the code to accomplish this but it doesn't seem to work with the way my webview app is setup.

I am a novice and have written all of my code from different tutorials, so If you could please explain where to put the code that would be helpful.

Here is my current .h file

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController1 : UIViewController

{
    IBOutlet UIWebView *myWebView;
}

@end
```

Here is my current .m file

```
#import "ViewController1.h"

@interface ViewController1 ()

@end

@implementation ViewController1


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Home", @"Home");
        self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"birdhouse"];
    }
    return self;
}



- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];


    {
        UIImage *navigationBarBackground = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];

        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navigationBarBackground forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    }


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://jbirdmedia.org/rcwc/iphone/home.html"];

    NSURLRequest *myRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL];

    [myWebView loadRequest:myRequest];

}





- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



@end
```

I've taken out all the code from my failed attempts so this code is currently my working app for viewcontroller1 and I have 4 ViewControllers for my 4 tabs.

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 0):

Well your code right now doesn't mention anything about an UIActivityIndicatorView. In your viewDidLoad method you need something like this:

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
activityView.center = myWebView.center;
[myWebView addSubview: activityView];
[activityView startAnimating];
```

Comment: I had taken out all of my failed attempts at the activityindicator thats why it wasn't showing anything.

By adding your code (and changing it to gray) I got a small gray spinning wheel, but it doesn't stop spinning after the content is loaded. Don't I have to add some kind of UIWebDidFinishLoad somewhere?

Also how can I customize the look of the loader? I would like to have some text with it that says "loading" and I would like all of it to be in a semi transparent bg like xcode uses when "build succeeded".

I thought I could use the interface builder for this but evidently not this way?

Comment: To get it to stop you'll want to implement the delegate method – webViewDidFinishLoad: and remove it from the webview. You could create a view that says loading in interface builder and then load the xib file and add it, but honestly it's probably easier to just create a UIView, add the UIActivityIndicatorView and a UILabel to it and then add that UIView to the webview, then remove it when the load finishes.

Comment: I understand the logic of what your saying but unfortunatly I don't know where to begin to do something like that. Could you explain in more detail for me?

Answer (score 0):

This is very rough and not tested but it should look something like this:

```
    UIView *loadingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 150)];
    loadingView.center = self.view.center;
    [loadingView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [loadingView setAlpha:0.75f];

    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,40,40);
    activityIndicator.center = loadingView.center;
    [loadingView addSubview:activityIndicator];
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];

    UILabel *loadingLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, loadingView.bounds.size.width, 50)];
    [loadingLabel setText:@"Loading"];
    [loadingLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [loadingLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [loadingLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [loadingView addSubview:loadingLabel];

    [self.webView addSubview:loadingView];
```

You'll need to adapt for the way you actually want the views to look, but that should get you pointed in the right direction.